# Faster way to write an integer vector to a binary file with C++?

Tags: c++, binaryfiles, stdvector

I currently have the following method for writing `vector<int>` objects to a binary file.

```
void save_config(std::string fname, std::vector<int> config) {
    std::ofstream out(fname);
    for (auto&& item : config)
        out << item;
}
```

The data I need to save, however, is on the order of 60 MB and takes about 5 seconds to write with this function. Furthermore, I have to write a binary file for each iteration of an algorithm I am running, and a single iteration for an input size which generates data on this order of magnitude is probably about 500 milliseconds.

I can mask the write time behind the algorithm's execution time but, with this difference in runtime, it won't really matter. Is there any way to improve my `save_config` function? Also, I'm using a binary file because I've ready that it is the fastest format to write to; but the specific format does not matter so, if someone has an alternate suggestion, I would be happy to hear it.

Comment: If it's a binary file, why not simply use `fwrite` or `out.write()` to write the entire vector buffer's contents without writing a loop?  Second, that `std::ofstream` you are showing is opened in text mode, not binary.

Comment: Also note that you need to indicate in the file the number of items you've written.  How will you read this back if you don't know how big to make the vector?  All of these things you need to take in consideration if you decide to write to a binary file -- you need to know how to properly interpret the file so that you can read it back properly.

Comment: `out << item;` writes text, not binary. You'd never be able to read that file back correctly. Let's say you have a vector with one entry of `111` so that's what your file contains. A vector with 3 entries of `1` or two entries of `11, 1` or `1, 11` would all give you the same file.

Comment: Be aware that there are big and little endian CPU and not every compiler use the same same for an `int`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whether or not it will result in a significantly faster operation will have to be tested, but the following use of the [`write()` function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/write) avoids iterating through the vector:

```cpp
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>

void save_config(std::string fname, std::vector<int> config)
{
    std::ofstream out(fname, std::ios_base::binary);
    uint64_t size = config.size();
    out.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&size), sizeof(size));
    out.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(config.data()), size * sizeof(int));
}
```

Note that I have also included a 'prefix' to record the size of the vector, so that this can be determined when later reading the data from the file; I have used a fixed-size type (64-bits) for this to avoid possible issues with platforms that have a 32-bit `size_t` type (you should perhaps consider using a fixed-size integer type, such as `int32_t`, to avoid similar issues).

Comment: You don't need to specify the `std::ios_base::out` flag explicitly when using `std::ofstream`, that flag is always implicit. But more importantly, you should not be using `operator<<` to write the vector's `size()`, use `out.write()` instead, otherwise it won't be readable back later.

Comment: @Remy Yes, of course - it's an `ofstream` so the `out` flag is there already! Your second point concerned a more serious error. See edits.